# show content to specific users in joomla 2.5 depending on user field?

Tags: joomla, field, joomla2.5

is it possible to show special content content to specific users depending on users stored on database in json format?

i searched and i couldnt find any component ,and is the cck a solution? or i have to create  a custom component?

I'm not a programer but I'm guessing that a simple component with a content plugin is a simple solution ? plugin check user fields before showing content if the fields is available it shows that content . like other plugins syntax ,am i right?

I just want to know can it be done ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 2.5 you can limit articles, categories etc to specific "Viewing Access Levels" without any extensions.

You can fine tune the visibility by "User Groups" that match up to one or more "Viewing Access Levels". You can read [the tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6) or checkout the [Joomla Community Article](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/639-Joomla-ACL-Access-Levels)

You can also automate this process using products like [Akeeba Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/19528) to automatically setup a users group based on the subscription they've taken out.

Comment: thank you for your reply but i mean specific users not group i found a plugin for content "Core Design Access Text plugin" but i need this function with user fields so it can be connected any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a NoNumber extension called AdvancedModuleManager (or so), with that you can assign modules to specific users...